# Generate dates for postgres

Tags: postgresql

i have a table

[image]

and i have a range from '2019-01-02' to '2019-01-04'

I need to generate ID and DATES (generated) from my table which **started_at** and **ended_at** (nullable) between the given range

result must be like this:

[image]

ID 4 from table is not included in result because it's started_at and ended_at not in range '2019-01-02' and '2019-01-04'

I need query that will do that in postgres.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `generate_series()`

```
select t.id, g.dt::date
from the_table t
  cross join generate_series(t.started_at::date + 1,
                             least(t.ended_at::date, date '2019-01-04'),
                             interval '1 day') as g(dt)
where t.started_at >= date '2019-01-02' 
  and t.started_at < date '2019-01-04';
```

Comment: I have an error: function generate_series(date, date) does not exist

Comment: @RIPOL92: sorry, forgot the third parameter

Answer (score 0):

Worked this variant:

```
select t.id, g.dt::date from the_table t 
cross join generate_series(t.started_at::date + 1, 
 least(t.ended_at::date, date '2019-01-04'), interval '1 day') as g(dt) 
where dt >= date '2019-01-02' and dt < date '2019-01-04';
```